# How to create a paragraph next to an ionic check box?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ionic-framework

[Trying to create something like this text that wraps onto more than one line and with the checkbox vertically centered relative to the lines.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLTt9.png)

Current code:

```
<div className = 'terms'>
   <IonCheckbox/>
   <span> paragraph </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.terms {
    margin-top: 10vw;
    font-style: italic;

    ion-checkbox {
      margin-right: 2vw;
    }
  }
```

I need the paragraph to be a left aligned block. Instead it just wraps around the checkbox. I've tried using a variety of of things like float: left on the check-box, display: block

Answer (score 2):

Use slot option in IonCheckbox

```
<IonItem>
        <IonLabel ><i>paragraph </i></IonLabel>
        <IonCheckbox slot="start" />
  </IonItem>
```

Comment: Label doesn't allow the text to wrap and cuts off everything after the first line of the paragraph.

Comment: Add this style to IonLabel
white-space: normal;

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to stick everything into a flexbox. I don't have ionic here but it should work fine. Wrap the checkbox with a div if necessary.

```html
<div className = 'terms' style="display:flex">
   <div><input type="checkbox"></div>
   <span> paragraph </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This gets the text into the block like shape I was looking for next to the checkbox, but for some reason it stretches the checkbox vertically into a weird elongated shape.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Ionic to know, but I would set a height and width on the wrapping div.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use flexbox;

```
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-start;
flex-direction: row;
```

Comment: This creates like a backwards L shape around the check box. I need it to be a left justified block next to the checkbox.

Comment: Actually sorry I was looking at my old code. This gets the text into the block shape I was looking for. However, it stretches the checkbox vertically into this weird elongated shape.

Answer (score 0):

```
ion-checkbox {
      vertical-align: top;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
    span {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 80%;
      font-style: italic;
      color: grey;
    }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.